# iPhone App Store ID required for Facebook requests to work?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an iOS app and I'm sending an invite from one user to another. The issue is that although the request is appearing on the recipients Facebook page on the Web (under App Centre), they don't appear on the Facebook iOS app.

I've read through the Getting Started FB docs and other threads, the main issue seems to be setting up the FB page correctly (if it isn't apparently FB wouldnt know what to do with the invite). I've done as suggested - however, I don't have a iPhone App Store ID so that's currently left blank.

Is this required? If so, how do you obtain one just for testing? If it's not required, what else am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say you have an error with "iPhone App Store ID required", or what?

Comment: I don't have an error with it - I just don't have an iPhone App Store ID so I haven't entered anything on the facebook app setup page.

Comment: got you, vice versa - you should get the App ID from facebook page and put the in the plist, the facebook does't need your Apple developer ID (or any Appstore ID)

Comment: Are you saying use the Facebook App ID until you get a Apple Store ID? Really? Tried it and it said this (unsurprisingly)

Warning

We were unable to retrieve your iPhone App Store ID from the iTunes App Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later.

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: strange.. may be I didnt understand the problem. What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,

As to me, I didn't have to fill out the "iPhone App Store ID" (I do not have one yet ...).

My issue was that I used a non verified account to test the App.

Do you have an error message in the FB class handler ?

Comment: Ah no - I just put in the App ID. I think perhaps it just needs some form of number there. It reported it can't find it, but it saves it and it worked after that.

Comment: I don't get it, in your previous post, you wrote " I don't have a iPhone App Store ID so that's currently left blank" . And here you say you punt in the App ID. Are you sure you don't mix up the FB App ID and the iPhone App Store App ID ?

Comment: I think you did, but just to be sure, did you follow the steps here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/